# PDF digital signature not working in Ghostscript while compression

Tags: command, ghostscript

`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dPrinted=true -dColorImageResolution=100 -dNOPAUSE  -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf`

Comment: Welcome @Aarti please add some information and your tests when you ask a question. Also add the code section that helps a lot with readbility.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript does not produce signed PDF files, so you can't be signing the file with Ghostscript.

If you mean that the output PDF file is not signed, then yes, correct, Ghostscript does not sign files.

The process for producing PDF files from Ghostscript is documented [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.54.0/VectorDevices.htm#Overview)

Given that the point of signing a file is that it proves the file has not been modified, how do you think you can produce a 'compressed' file while maintaining the signature ? For example, the command line you have supplied there specifically downsamples the resolution of colour images, which clearly modifies the file.